# Missing namespace after new Kendo UI 2014 Q1 added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I added the new kendo 2014 Q1 to my mvc project, but my classes that were using the namespace kendo.mvc now have this error:

> ```
>  The type or namespace name 'Kendo' could not be found (are you missing
>  a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> ```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it.
It's about .net framework. kendo ui 2014Q1 is match with .net framework 4.5.
So you can't add it to a project by .net framework 4.
Unless , you create a new telerik mvc project in visual studio and choose .net framework 4 and finish it. after that you can go to bin directory and copy Kendo.MVC file and add it to your project.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can you explain in brief didn't understand your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you're facing this problem when running the build definition, just put your Kendo.Mvc.dll library in your solution folder, for example, under packages folder and check that in TFS.